# Html tags with in the div in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need get HTML tags within the div

```
<div class="div1">
   <a>etc</a>
   <p>etc</p>
</div>
```

how to get html content within a `div1` in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this alert html content

```
alert($(".div1").html());
```

use this initialising

```
   var $a=$(".div1").html();
```

Comment: The question is _I need get HTML tags within the div_ not entire html inside the div!

Answer (score 1):

try this

***HTML***

```
<div class="div1">
   <a>etc</a>
   <p>etc</p>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$('.div1').children().text();
```

Comment: The question was _I need get HTML tags within the div_ not the html content of tags inside the div!

Answer (score 0):

use `$("div1").html('<h1>this is html!</h1>');` to set.

use `$("#div1").html();` to get

Comment: This sets the html, not get it

Comment: maybe wait for me to finish my answer?

Comment: then don't post half of it and start off with what's really needed :)?

Comment: you have a point there. Though posting halve an answer quickly, to then edit it as a complete one is normal here. Answering goes so fast that you have to be quick about it

Comment: Yes I know but how should I know *you're not finished*? I'd rather add a comment and be sure about it

Comment: The question is _I need get HTML tags within the div_ not entire html inside the div!

Comment: @eregrith, maybe wait atleast 5 seconds after I posted? :)
But yeah, I get it :) no worries, just throught a downvote is a bit harsh

Comment: yeah but I was there keeping an eye to remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the raw content use :

```
var contents = $(".div1").html()
```

For example on [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Html) you have this:

```
$("p").click(function () {
  var htmlStr = $(this).html();
  $(this).text(htmlStr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method. If you don't pass it any content, it work as a getter.

```
var content = $(".div1").html();
```

The `content` variable will contain the HTML as a JavaScript string.

Comment: The question is _I need get HTML tags within the div_ not entire html inside the div!

Comment: @dshai Well, I'd say its vague. The question also states `How to get html content within a div1?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlContent = $(".div1").html();
```

if you want want only the tag name then try with the following code:

```
alert($('.div1').children()[0].tagName);
```

The above code returns you the tag name in BLOCK letter. like "A", "P" etc. Change the index number then print it.

here is the working sample: 
[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb3ey/)

Comment: The question is _I need get HTML tags within the div_ not entire html inside the div!

Answer (score 0):

can you add id properties to the elements as such:

```
<a id="a1"></a>
```

That way you can access it as such:

```
$("#a1")
```

unless you are just going for the content for processing then use .html as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This gives u just the tags:

```
$('.div1').children().each(function(i, item) {
    alert(this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bCM7L/